# Is a network socket an API or a REGISTRY?

Tags: sockets, networking

I'm studying about network sockets, but unfortunately I couldn't understand if the so-called sockets are DATA or API...

I'm more tempted to believe that a network socket is a kernel-level object that serves as an in-memory register containing data that associates a process with another process to allow communication, and that register (socket network) has data that describes the type of communication that must be performed by the kernel. Some of the information that exists in this type of record that we call a network socket is an IP address, port number, an identifier and etc... So I believe that the kernel uses this dataset (socket) to make the connection.
Note that my definition is different from saying that "network sockets are an API", because in my view they are more for data than for a programming interface instance.
I would like to know if my definition makes sense or am I misunderstanding this concept?

Comment: It is neither. A socket is an endpoint of a communication link. There is an API that deals with sockets, but that doesn't make a socket an API. Similarly, it has data associated with it, but that doesn't make a registry.  Don't overthink this.

Comment: @user207421 Saying that "a socket is an endpoint of a communication link" is too generic, several things that aren't sockets also fit your definition. What I needed was to understand what in essence a socket is.

Comment: Several things such as what? This is the generally accepted definition. Trying to shoehorn sockets as APIs or Registries isn't the way forward.

Comment: "An endpoint of a communication link" can be a controller method, a reverse proxy server, any middleware on the network...

Comment: And they all have a socket as the actual endpoint.

Comment: perfect, but when you say "this is an endpoint of a communication link" how do you know if you are referring to middleware or a socket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if i understand well your question.

- a network socket is more related to IPC (Inter-Process Communications) mechanisms.[what is an IPC? (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). So it rely on the same principle than pipes, named pipes, shared memory etc... but act differently.
- The way it is implemented is very dependant of the OS you are looking at. It mainly rely on kernel functions (C programming language for Linux -> [see here](https://linux-kernel-labs.github.io/refs/heads/master/labs/networking.html)) involving dedicated data spaces and buffers.
  The data space and buffer allocation is made in the same way than when you declare a string=helloworld (or more complex structures) when writing an executable in C.
- Modern operating systems does provides upper-level interfaces for manipulating those functions (i.e opening a socket). You may call it API, but the rest of the world is calling it:  [SYSTEM CALLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call)

Hope it helps. :)

EDIT (On linux systems):

In userland (ring 3), when process open a socket, it makes calls to linux API for network/sockets, and this API (system calls), rely on kernel functions (ring 0).

Those kernel functions are C classes, storing related data in a reserved memory (as C objects).

- So for userland: the sockets are API.
- for kernel: sockets are DATA structures.

there is also executable code coming from static functions in the TCP/IP stack and drivers executed by the kernel point of view...and relying on the data structures created from the API system calls (from the userland)

Is it clearer? ahah ;).

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific in my question, allow me to rephrase it.
My question is:
Does creating a network socket mean creating a record in memory? or does creating a network socket mean instantiating an API (executable code)?

Comment: I edited the answer, maybe it will better answer your question? -> In short, i would say both.

Comment: @petradisgris  first I would like to thank you for the answers. And based on what you said, it makes sense to say that network sockets are actually data structures that only exist at the kernel level, at the user level what exists is an API responsible for creating the sockets, but this API is not characterized as a socket, but rather a mechanism used by user-level processes to create sockets. Meu raciocínio está correto?

Comment: Ya herr general! :). At least, it's my understanding of the mechanism.